# Issue with realurl, redirect and caching in TYPO3

Tags: redirect, caching, typo3, realurl, pibase

This error occures in TYPO3 7.6.10 with a piBase extension and realurl 2.0.15:

In this extension, I'm checking for a GET parameter, e.g. a country. If this parameter is not provided, I redirect to the same page, with default country as parameter:

```
if(!$this->piVars['country']) {
  $this->piVars['country'] = 'germany';
  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::redirect($this->pi_linkTP_keepPIvars_url(array(), true), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::HTTP_STATUS_303);
}
```

That means, the visitor e.g. calls url www.mypage.com/list/ and is redirected to www.mypage.com/list/germany/

This works fine, but after some time passes and some visitors were an the page, the redirect stopped working. When opening www.mypage.com/list/ in the browser, the page is displayed for some country (not the default one, e.g. for country "france"). That means, TYPO3 creates on page www.mypage.com/list/france/ a cache entry for page www.mypage.com/list/, but for this url, a cache entry should've never been created, because of the redirect.

I can reproduce this error by setting caching time of the page to 1 minute. Then I wait one minute, then loading the url www.mypage.com/list/france/. Now, when opening www.mypage.com/list/, there is no redirect and france is shown.

When disabling realurl (or just removing parameter "country" from realurl configuration), this error doesn't occur.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version?

Comment: Are you using chash caching and do you have your parameter included in the chash calculations?

Comment: TYPO3 6.2.15 and 7.6.10

Comment: When I disable realurl, I see the cHash parameter for the links generated by the extension. I also do not exclude parameter "country" in "cHashExcludedParameters", so I assume, this parameter is included in the cHash calculation.

Comment: I can reproduce this error: I set caching time of the page to 1 minute. Then I wait one minute, then loading the url www.mypage.com/list/france/. Now, when opening www.mypage.com/list/, there is no redirect and france is shown.

Comment: Sorry for wrong informations. The redirect is not the problem, even without redirect, I have the problem, that after clearing frontend cache and opening url www.mypage.com/list/france/, url www.mypage.com/list/ shows the same contents. When disabling realurl, this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Can you, please update your question? Bcs now it is a bite misleading: "realurl isn't the problem" from question and "When disabling realurl, this problem doesn't occur" from comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described here: [realurl generates entries without cHash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653271/realurl-generates-entries-without-chash)

Since version 2.0.15, realurl doesn't calculate the cHash parameter for links, which are accessed directly and which need a cHash parameter to show the right cached contents, like detail pages of a record.

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 stores in cache so-called "versions" of a page with corresponding **cHash** and additionaly a version without cHash - kind of a "default" page.

If something wrong happens, when cHash is validated by the core, it gets rejected and page is generated, using provided params in url.

In case of very first hit (cache is empty) and a wrong cHash page is generated, using the params from URL, but due to a wrong cHash this version is then understood as "default" and stored in cache.

The real reason you need to find in your code. It can be a wrong combination of RealURL configuration and code.
E.g. [enableCHashCache](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/realurl/Realurl/Configuration/ConfigurationDirectives/Index.html#code-enablechashcache) is set to `false` in RealURL configuration, but link is provided w/out cHash.

I can't tell you the exact reason, but you can check it different ways:

1. Set `FE - pageNotFoundOnCHashError` at Install Tool and check if 404 error happens, when you visit www.mypage.com/list/france/
2. Disable RealURL and visit different versions of a page with different `country` values - does `cHash` change for different countries or stays the same?
3. Check the url, generated by `pi_linkTP_keepPIvars_url()` with and without RealURL. Does it contain `cHash`?

Comment: Everything is configured the right way: enableCHashCache is true, 1. pageNotFoundOnCHashError is true and no 404 page is shown, 2. cHash changes for different countries, 3. url contains cHash

Comment: @Sven 3. url contains cHash also with RealURL enabled?

Comment: With RealURL enabled, the url doesn't contain cHash. RealURL strips the cHash and stores it in table "tx_realurl_urlcache" in column "original_url".

Comment: @Sven ok, so seems, that reason is found in your another question, answered by author of RealURL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676203/2070270

Comment: Yes, you are right. The cHash parameter isn't calculated, realurl generates no cHash parameter for url www.mypage.com/list/france/.